# DITA PDF rendition cover page customization

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to include the content of the below dita topic file on my cover page, but so far I have not been able.

The file that I need to include on the cover page is located on the local system and is referenced by the bookmap.

I am using DITA-OT 1.4.2 along with RenderX Xep.

I need to use this because I have a few books to render to PDF and the cover page change based on the book.

Here is my cover page content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
       outputclass="frontmatter"  id="topic010"
       ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.0"
       domains="(topic ui-d) (topic hi-d) (topic pr-d) (topic sw-d)                          (topic ut-d)"
       class="- topic/topic ">
   <title class="- topic/title ">Front Matters</title>
   <body class="- topic/body ">
      <image width="500"
             id="image_forewordheader"
             placement="inline"
             alt="heading"
             href="heading.png"
             class="- topic/image "/>
      <p outputclass="subject" class="- topic/p "> Subject test heading </p>
      <image height="10"
             width="500"
             id="img010"
             alt="image010"
             href="image010.png"
             placement="inline"
             class="- topic/image "/>
      <p class="- topic/p ">Some content goes here. This is a test front matter content.
      </p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">  </p>
      <p class="- topic/p ">  </p>

      <p class="- topic/p ">
         <image href="image011.png"
            alt="image011"
            id="image011"
            placement="inline"
            class="- topic/image "/>
      </p>
   </body>
</topic>
```

I am using the front-matter_1.0.xsl file to generate my cover page with the following template.

```
<xsl:template name="createFrontMatter_1.0">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="front-matter" xsl:use-attribute-sets="__force__page__count">
            <xsl:call-template name="insertFrontMatterStaticContents"/>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__frontmatter">
                    <!-- set the title -->
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__frontmatter__title">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$map/*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')][1]">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="$map/*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')][1]"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="$map//*[contains(@class,' bookmap/mainbooktitle ')][1]">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="$map//*[contains(@class,' bookmap/mainbooktitle ')][1]"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="//*[contains(@class, ' map/map ')]/@title">
                                <xsl:value-of select="//*[contains(@class, ' map/map ')]/@title"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/descendant::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')][1]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </fo:block>

                    <!-- set the subtitle -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$map//*[contains(@class,' bookmap/booktitlealt ')]"/>

                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__frontmatter__owner">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$map//*[contains(@class,' bookmap/bookmeta ')]"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>Preface </xsl:text>
                </fo:block>

       <!--         <xsl:call-template name="createPreface"/>-->

       <!—Use topic content front matter topic   as cover page     -->


                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__frontmatter__owner">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[contains(@outputclass,'frontmatter')]"/>
                </fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
```

Comment: What’s your actual question?

Comment: Thanks Buck, my question is how can I use a dita topic file from the file system as my cover page? The topic that I want to use is also referenced in bookmap. So far I have not been able to. I am only able to use bookmeta information from the bookmap to show on my book cover page. Hopefully this clarification will help in understanding what I need.

Comment: I don’t understand. You want to reference two files from one XSL file, right? What do you want the output to look like? What does the input from the other file look like?

Comment: The problem I need to solve is use a custom cover page while converting my dita bookmap to fo then to PDF. Currently , it is only possible for me to use the metadata from the bookmap on the cover page such as publication date, revision date, author, series etc. But What I need is to use one topic/page from the book that I am transforming as cover page or in other words just set a specific page as first page of the rendered book. This may be simple but I have not figured out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Placing a topic as cover page is not provided.

WIth recent DITA versions (DITA 1.2/DITA-OT1.8.5)++ There are a few strategies pointing in another direction:

1. Use DITA 1.2 key definitions combined with DITAVAL filtering to place "publication specific" content dynamically to the cover page.
   e.g.

   - Place product-specific keys in your bookmap elements like `<title><ph keyref="productName"/><title>`
   - Place the cover art as a image keyref in the title tag like `<title><image keyref="product/imageID"/><title>`
2. Make a specialization of the `org.dita.pdf2` plugin (DITA-OT 1.8.5 or higher) for each publication type and place individual background images in `front-matter.xsl`.

   ```
   <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute"
             top="-2cm" left="-2cm" width="21cm" height="29.7cm" background-repeat="no-repeat"
             background-image="Customization/OpenTopic/common/artwork/ManualCoverPageA4_V2-01.png">
             <fo:block/>
           </fo:block-container>
   ```